# Listeners being added repeatedly, but can't figure how. I'm using one() and then a timer to re-enable it on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Open the JavaScript console, activate the below snippet, then click on the Aqua yes/no button. Say ***five*** times. It executes properly (just prints something to console) each time. Then click on any other button. It executes ***five*** times (at least). You can then click on a third button for a dance party strobe light.

Why?

I'm first enabling the listener for the button with [`one('click', processLike)`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), so it executes exactly once and then drops the listener. Then, after processing the click (printing to the console), the listener is re-established after a 500 millisecond pause.

```js
var processLike = function()  {
   //The value of the "data-color_id" attribute.
   var color_id = $(this).data('color_id');
   console.log(color_id);
   /*
       Don't process requests too close together. Attack prevention.
    */
   var millsToIgnoreClicks = 500;
   console.log('Like disabled for: ' + millsToIgnoreClicks);
   setTimeout(function() {
      enableLikeListenerOnce();
   }, millsToIgnoreClicks);
};
$(document).ready(function()  {
   enableLikeListenerOnce();
});
var enableLikeListenerOnce = function()  {
   console.log("Like enabled");
   $('.td__toggle_color_like_button').one('click', processLike);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
         <th>Color</th>
         <th>Favorite?</th>
      </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">aqua</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_12" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="12">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">black</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_13" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="13">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">blue</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_14" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="14">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">fuchsia</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_15" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="15">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">gray</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_16" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="16">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">green</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_17" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="17">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">lime</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_18" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="18">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">maroon</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_19" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="19">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">navy</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_20" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="20">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">olive</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_21" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="21">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">orange</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_22" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="22">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">purple</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_23" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="23">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">red</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_24" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="24">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">silver</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_25" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="25">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">teal</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_26" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="26">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">white</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_27" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="27">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">yellow</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_28" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="28">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
   </table>
```

This is a trivial demo of the concept I'm trying to use here: Process the first request, then ignore all others for X milliseconds. After that, re-establish the listener. Again, open the console before using this.

```js
function onClick() {
    var ms = 2000;
    console.log('Disabled for: ' + ms);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Re-enabled');
        $(this).one('click', onClick);
    }, ms);
}

$('button').one('click', onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Link</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling

```js
$('.td__toggle_color_like_button').one('click', processLike);
```

which will bind the click to all the dom selector with class **td__toggle_color_like_button** again including the current click button.

Try the below (JavaScript different, HTML the same).

```js
    var processLike = function()  {
       //The value of the "data-color_id" attribute.
       var color_id = $(this).data('color_id');
       console.log(color_id);
       /*
           Don't process requests too close together. Attack prevention.
        */
       var millsToIgnoreClicks = 500;
       console.log('Like disabled for: ' + millsToIgnoreClicks);
       var _this = this;
       setTimeout(function() {
          enableLikeListenerOnce(_this);
       }, millsToIgnoreClicks);
    };
    $(document).ready(function()  {
       $('.td__toggle_color_like_button').one('click', processLike);
    });
    var enableLikeListenerOnce = function(dom)  {
       console.log("Like enabled");
       $(dom).one('click', processLike);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
         <th>Color</th>
         <th>Favorite?</th>
      </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">aqua</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_12" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="12">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">black</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_13" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="13">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">blue</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_14" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="14">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">fuchsia</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_15" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="15">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">gray</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_16" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="16">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">green</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_17" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="17">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">lime</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_18" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="18">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">maroon</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_19" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="19">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">navy</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_20" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="20">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">olive</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_21" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="21">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">orange</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_22" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="22">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">purple</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_23" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="23">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">red</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_24" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="24">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">silver</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_25" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="25">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">teal</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_26" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="26">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">white</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_27" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="27">
               <button class="button_liked">Yes</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="td__color_name">yellow</td>
            <td id="toggle_color_like_cell_28" class="td__toggle_color_like_button" data-color_id="28">
               <button class="button_unliked">No</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: I see!! It's re-applying it to every button, but only turning it off for the just-clicked button. I don't understand `$(dom).one`. Can you please explain that? This does work, but I'm wondering if this solution has any side effects or other consequences I need to be aware of. Is there a more precise/specific way to re-turn on only the just-clicked-on button?

Comment: Oh, wait a minute! You're passing in `this` to `enableLikeListenerOnce`, which is the current button. Excellent! I thought `dom` was something special. Didn't catch the parameter.

Comment: @aliteralmind the `dom` in the function **enableLikeListenerOnce** just refer to the DOM Node of the current clicked button, which is `this` in the **processLike** function. The point is to bind only to the DOM Node which trigger the function and not to all. I hope that clears it.